# SVG sprites in helper function

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I use svg sprites like this:

`<svg><use href="combined.svg#filter_sent"></use></svg>`

In a `Meteor/Blaze` template helper, svg sprites are not rendered:

```
<div class="colorset">
    {{{color}}}
</div>


color: function () {
    if (this.color && !this.validate) {
        return '<svg><use href="combined.svg#green"></use></svg>';
    }
    if (this.color && this.certain) {
        return '<svg><use href="combined.svg#orange"></use></svg>';
    } else {
        return '<svg><use href="combined.svg#red"></use></svg>';
    }
}
```

=> Inside the `use` > `shadow-root`, nothing is inserted.

Comment: Please add the HTML part of the template

Comment: @Jankapunkt Done - nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of error possibilities, best if you post all your code.

One possibility: Not matching template name to helper function declaration.  e.g.

In html file:

```
<template name="foo">
...
```

In js file:

```
Template.bar.helpers({ ....
```

(this bites me more often than I care to admit)

I do not know what you mean by

> => Inside the `use` > `shadow-root`, nothing is inserted.

Using the chrome inspector you can choose the element you want to examine and see if it is has been rendered in the page really easily.

Comment: I don't think there is any error - not in template names for sure. SVG sprites make, anywhere else than in a helper, `<svg><use href="combined.svg#filter_sent"></use></svg>` rendering in `<svg><use href="combined.svg#filter_sent">*SVGwithPathHere*</use></svg>`